# Design pattern for returning false instead of throwing error

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I am working on a Python project to scrape data from various external sources. Everything is Object Oriented except for a few scripts that just  instantiate some objects and call a couple methods. So all the logic is in different classes.
I don't really have any concrete code to illustrate my point.

Basically I have a function that tries to scrape a URL and if successful returns the data else returns false. 
The return value from this gets used by another function `saveData()` to save the data to a file. If the scrape was unsuccessful and returned false then `saveData()` returns false. Then this gets passed on and lets say it keeps going.

The reason `scrape()` returns false instead of throwing an error is that I will use this in a script to scraper many URLs and I don't want it to die because of one bad URL.

I don't really like the idea of this "trickling down" effect, where I have to check for a false value all the way down, just to avoid an error.

The ideal solution would be to stop processing that URL once it fails to scrape it. I feel like this is a common situation that may have some design pattern to avoid it?

Maybe this is too abstract for SO.

Comment: It is definitely not an answer but I've played lately with [an idea of implementing Try-like class in Python](https://github.com/zero323/tryingsnake). Maybe you'll find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you asking, it is to find a clean way to bail out early when scraping a URL fails. In this case I would use `filter` and `map` with a sentinal value:

```
# only used if in python 2
from future_builtins import map, filter

# just make sure your sentinal is a value that cannot be possibly considered valid
_sentinal = None
def scrape(url):
    try:
        return attempt_scrape(url)
    except Exception:
        return _sentinal

url_data = map(scrape, sequence_of_urls)
good_scrapes = filter(lambda v: v is not _sentinal, url_data)  # only return the values we want
saved = map(saveData, good_scrapes)

# force running the chained iterators now
for s in saved:
    pass
```